# How to implement a rollback on a series of updates

Tags: angular, firebase

When executing a number of update transactions on a list of documents if one or more of the documents is not in a particular state then none can be updated. What is the best way of doing this

I need to update a status field on a set of documents in a collection that have a particular value for another field - call it group. I query the collection based on the group field this returns a snapshot list I iterate over with forEach. On each iteration I need to update the status of the document to a new status - but only if it already has a particular status. If it does not then none of the documents in the group must be updated.
Typically this would require a roll back of sorts. There does not seem to be a rollback option for batch or transactions in firebase - I am wondering if the following is valid.

In the loop add the updates to the batch. If at the end of the loop all are valid return the commit otherwise send back a rejected Promise.

The question is - is leaving the batch like that acceptable or are there side effects?

```
interface IDoc {
   Status: string,
   Time: any
}

async processBatch(group:string) : Promise<void>
{
  const batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();
  let snapshot = await this.afs.collection('Docs', ref => ref.where('Group', '==', gropup).get().toPromise();
  let valid:boolean = true;
  snapshot.forEach(item => {
    const doc = item.data() as IDoc;
    if (valid && doc.Status === 'Complete') {
      batch.update(item.ref, {Status: 'Approve', Time: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
    }
    else {
       valid = false;
    }
  });
  return valid ? batch.commit() : Promise.reject();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can abandon a batch simply by not committing it.  That's not a problem.  You can also abort a transaction by simply returning a rejected promise (at least on the normal JavaScript API).